# SignalR with DNS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dns, signalr

I am creating a chat system within my mobile app, but I am running into a problem. I have defined jQuery and the signalR within my index. I also have defined the script path to my server.

**Code** (index.html)

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <!-- Cordova whitelist plugin -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline' *">

    <!-- Base libs -->
    <script src="libs/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- Third party libs -->
    <script src='libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='libs/signalR/jquery.signalR.min.js'></script>

    <!-- Location for SignalR lib to open a connection with  -->
    <script src="http://www.mytestserver.nl/chathub/signalr/hubs"></script>  

    <!-- Application Javascript files | put the routing files after the controllers! -->
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have a working version on my localhost, so I do think my code is right. 
When I try to use the code in my controller I get a 404 not found error. 
I think this is because I do not define a port in my script to the server. Then signalR defaults to the current host (localhost:8100).

**Code** (chatController.js)

```
.controller('ChatController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
       $.connection.hub.url = "http://www.mytestserver.nl/chathub/signalr"; 
       $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
       console.log("hello world");
    });
}]);
```

Not the DNS comes in. I cannot define a port number, because the DNS is removing the port numbers. Defining any port number results in a 404 not found or a Connection timed out error.

What can I do to make a connection to the server?

Comment: jquery and angularjs are not really compatible, I hope you are aware of that.

Comment: on top you are not including angularjs in the index.html...

Comment: @thegio 1) SignalR is a jQuery based lib so I cannot realy chose. I need to use jQuery for the connection. 

2) I am using Ionic. The Ionic script I am including also holds an AngularJS script

Answer (score 0):

Ive had this situation before which worked fine on devexpress localhost but when transferred to IIS the path would not map correctly.

Its possible that the path you specify to signalr/hubs is not correct so the server does not pick it up correctly.

Try adding a wildcard to your signalr/hubs  reference like this

`<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>`

After this open the javascript console and ensure that there are no errors.